# Why is gradual underflow so important _mathematically_?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I have read ([Kahan](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ARITH_17U.pdf)) that one of the reasons subnormals (denormals) have been proposed was to insure that the gap between adjacent floating points retains monotonicity until reaching zero and that was crucial to construct some mathematical proofs.
My question: I am looking for a quite simple example for such a situation. That is, a *programming* example that converges by assuming real numbers have exact representation but when using floating points the mathematical proof of its convergence does not hold without monotonicity.

Comment: Did you read http://floating-point-gui.de/ ?

Comment: I just completed it by I found no answer to my question.

Comment: As far as I know, the decision to allow subnormal numbers has no mathematical basis, and has everything to do with trying to squeeze extra precision out of the `binary32` and `binary64` floating-point formats.

Comment: @Xirema, Please see page 4/15 in the link: Unlike  GU,  AU  lacks the crucial property that the gaps between a floating-point number  x  and its nearest neighbors not increase when  |x|  decreases.  Though not always a bad thing,  this lack undermines some error-analyses and proofs.

Comment: This is dated, just a plea to get people involved with computation to deal with the fact that computers need to compute with less than infinite precision.  A problem that nobody wants to deal with.  Kahan makes the plea for the end-user.  That user does not want to have to talk to the mathematician that designed a math model that is based on ideal assumptions.  Or the programmer who wants to deal with non-ideal machine behavior by generating an error.  The end-user just wants to trudge along and increase the error bar.  Kahan won.

Comment: @HansPassant Did you mean that there is no solid scientific argument supporting gradual underflow but perhaps a commercial goal?

Comment: Just practical.  Kahan was instrumental in getting denormal support added to IEEE-754, talking programmers into using it took a lot of convincing.   We despise it.

Comment: One simple problem: Assuming `a,b,c` are not `NAN`, `if (a != b) (c / (a - b))` will never divide by zero assuming gradual underflow. On the other hand, without denormals, `a - b` can produce zero even for `a != b`.

Comment: @EOF, I am sorry but I do not see the use of monotonicity in your argument.